# nservicebus a client sends command to msmq and azure service queue

Tags: nservicebus, msmq, azure-queues

I would like to know how, if possible, a client app (winform) sends NServicebus command **A** to be processed by a MSMQ queue and command **B** to be processed by a Azure storage queue or Azure service bus? If not, how may I get around of it?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, there is now a [transport bridge](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/) which is specifically for this scenario: bridging messages between two different transports.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help? https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/azure-service-bus-msmq-bridge/

````
Common examples include:

A hybrid solution that spans across endpoints deployed on-premises and in a cloud environment.
Departments within organization integrating their systems that use different messaging technologies for historical reasons.
Traditionally, such integrations would require native messaging or relaying. Bridging is an alternative, allowing endpoints to communicate over different transports without a need to get into low-level messaging technology code. With time, when endpoints can standardize on a single transport, bridging can be removed with a minimal impact on the entire system.```
````

Comment: The scenario I have is that I have a win form app that need to talk to a service hosted in Azure (using Azure Service Bus) and to another service hosted locally using MSMQ.